# c# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#

I am trying to move a image file and I got the error. I am sure the file is not opened from another external program. I restarted my computer and nothing changed. Why do I get this error? Is it about `DirectoryInfo` ?

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\gphoto-2.4.14-win32-build2\\win32");
                FileInfo[] smFiles = di.GetFiles("*.jpg");
                if (smFiles!=null)
                {
                    string from = "C:\\gphoto-2.4.14-win32-build2\\win32\\capt0000.jpg";
                    string to = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location + "\\capt0000.jpg";

                    File.Move(from, to); // Try to move
                }
```

Comment: How many files with jpg extension are present in your source folder?

Comment: What is your exact exception ? Can you provide it. And that may related with admin rights did you checked it ?

Comment: @Steve 3 files with jpg extensions

Comment: So after the first move, you try again to move a now inexistant file over the file that you have just finished to move in the previous loop? Perhaps you should revise the logic in this loop.

Comment: `I am sure the file is not opened from another program` Don't be so sure... this is your problem...

Comment: @Steve No, there is no loop there. capt0000.jpg is in the directory.

Comment: @CihanUygun how can I check it?

Comment: @ffttyy can you try to run Visual Studio as Administrator ?

Comment: @Eser I am sure and check the answer. Poor humor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` is file not a directory.

Use `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)` instead.